# Is it possible to use a Windows batch file to delete certain rar files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rar

I am trying to use a batch file to delete .rar files from a certain folder which are older than 30 days. However the batch file I have right now deletes any file older than 30 days, I want to limit this just to .rar files. My code is below.

```
REM *******************************************************************
REM Deleting database backups older than 30 days. 

@echo off
@Echo Deleting database backups older than 30 days...
rem echo y|forfiles /p C:\Batch\Archives\*.rar /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @path"

pause  

EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `forfiles` help, you will see that the `/P` parameter is just for the path. You need to use the `/M` parameter for a file mask. So you should use this:

```
forfiles /p C:\Batch\Archives /m *.rar /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

In my case, there's no need to echo an 'y' to confirm. But if in your case `del` is asking for confirmation, just use its `/Q` parameter.

On a side not, there's no need to use `@` again after using `@echo off`. You either use `@echo off` in the first line or place a `@` before each line, doing both is not necessary and makes your file uglier.
Furthermore, I would place the `@echo off` before those `REM`s so they are not displayed. If you want to show those messages, just use `echo`. The final `EXIT` is also not needed.